# Unix: multi and single character delimiter in cut or awk commands

Tags: unix, awk, sed, cut

This is the string I have:

```
my_file1.txt-myfile2.txt_my_file3.txt
```

I want to remove all the characters after the first "_" that follows the first ".txt".

From the above example, I want the output to be `my_file1.txt-myfile2.txt`. I have to search for first occurrence of ".txt" and continue parsing until I find the underscore character, and remove everything from there on.

Is it possible to do it in sed/awk/cut etc commands?

Comment: As you can see from some of the answers you've received your example doesn't adequately test your requirements. Right now various scripts could produce the expected output you post from the sample input you post without actually doing what you want, i.e. `remove all the characters after the first "_" that follows the first ".txt"`. It's usually a good idea to provide more than a single line of sample input/output so we can adequately test a potential solution against your full requirements as covered by those examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this job with `cut` but you can with sed and awk:

```
$ sed 's/\.txt/\n/g; s/\([^\n]*\n[^_]*\)_.*/\1/; s/\n/.txt/g' file
my_file1.txt-myfile2.txt

$ awk 'match($0,/\.txt[^_]*_/){print substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-2)}' file
my_file1.txt-myfile2.txt
```

Comment: It would be very useful to the readers if you can explain the sed command you used.

Comment: I think it's pretty common idiomatic sed - is there any part of it you don't understand after a glance at the man page?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples.

```
awk '{sub(/\.txt_.*/,".txt")} 1' Input_file
```

Simply substituting everything from .txt_ to till last of line with .txt and printing the line here